# Is it safe to target sdk version 33 (Android 13)?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

So I have seen that Android 13 has been officially released. But, when I searched for it in the official page, I have seen that it appears as beta version: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms#13

So, my question is, is it better to wait some time so that it is safe to target that Android 13 version?

Answer (score 3):

I would say - it depends on your app, but mostly sure, it's safe. For example, we faced a couple of issues with the notification permission and a foreground service and it took some time to fix and test it, and it's always better to test such things on a real device rather than an emulator with a strange behaviour coming from the newest system image. If you don't have any particular/hardware places which should be tested on a physical device only, then I think that it's safe enough - you'll have plenty of time to fix any random roughnesses :)

Comment: Were you able to solve compilation issues came while changing targetSdk = 33

Comment: @gauravD we had only nullability issues which came from, mmm, Geocoder, I recall, so yeah, nothing else and nothing major.

Comment: @PineapplePie, Did you get any issue with foreground serivice for Android 13?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe, Mine is given below in android/build
.gradle

```
 ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
    minSdkVersion = 23
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    androidXCore = "1.6.0"
    kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
}
```